# Find the analytical solution to the following set of coupled ODEs (Eigenvector): $\frac{dx}{dt}=y$ and $\frac{dy}{dt}=-x$

Tags: calculus

Find the analytical solution to the following set of coupled ODE
$$\frac{dx}{dt}=y$$
$$\frac{dy}{dt}=-x$$

and also given that at time, $t=0$

$$\begin{pmatrix}
x\\ 
y
\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}
0\\ 
1
\end{pmatrix}$$

My attempt,

I started by finding the eigenvalue of the matrice of $\begin{pmatrix}
0 &1 \\ 
 -1&0 
\end{pmatrix}$ and I got $\lambda=\pm i$.
So that $$(A-\lambda I)v=0$$
When $\lambda =i$
$$\begin{pmatrix} -i &1 \\  -1&-i 
\end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix}v_1\\v_2 \end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}
0\\0 
\end{pmatrix}$$

After "Reduced-row echelon form",
I got $$\begin{pmatrix} 1 &i \\  0&0 
\end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix}v_1\\v_2 \end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}
0\\0 
\end{pmatrix}$$

$$v_1+iv_2=0$$
Let $$v_1=k$$
$$v_2=\frac{k}{-i}$$

$$\therefore \begin{pmatrix}v_1\\v_2 \end{pmatrix}=k\begin{pmatrix}1\\\frac{-1}{i} \end{pmatrix}=k\begin{pmatrix}-i\\1\end{pmatrix}$$

Eigenvector is $$\begin{pmatrix}
-i\\1 \end{pmatrix}$$.

How should I continue?

Comment: Find the other eigenvector $w$ for $-i$, then the solution is $\alpha v+\beta w$. Choose $\alpha,\beta$ so the solution is real and satisfies initial condition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find the second eigenvector for the second eigenvalue. But in the complex case you can easily deduce the second eigenvector from the first one:
$$v_1=\pmatrix {-i \\ 1} \implies v_2=\pmatrix {i \\ 1}$$
Then the solution of the system
$X'=AX$ is:
$$X(t)=c_1e^{\lambda_1t}v_1+c_2e^{\lambda_2t}v_2$$

---

***Edit1***
I got this as  the solution of the system:
$$X(t)=c_1e^{\lambda_1t}v_1+c_2e^{\lambda_2t}v_2$$
$$X(t)=c_1e^{it}\pmatrix {-i \\ 1}+c_2e^{-it}\pmatrix {i \\ 1}$$
$$X(t)=c_1(\cos t +i \sin t)\pmatrix {-i \\ 1}+c_2 (\cos t -i \sin t)\pmatrix {i \\ 1}$$
$$X(t)=c_1\pmatrix {-i\cos t + \sin t \\ \cos t +i \sin t}+c_2 \pmatrix {i\cos t +\sin t \\ \cos t -i \sin t}$$
$$X(t)= \pmatrix {i(c_2-c_1)\cos t +(c_1+c_2)\sin t \\(c_1+c_2) \cos t -i (c_2-c_1)\sin t}$$
Substitute $B=i(c_2-c_1)$ and $A=(c_2+c_1)$:
$$X(t)= \pmatrix {B\cos t +A\sin t \\A \cos t - B\sin t}$$
Or more simply :
$$X(t)=A\pmatrix {\sin t \\ \cos t  }+B\pmatrix {\cos t \\  -\sin t}$$

Comment: Following your hint, I got 

$X(t)=c_1\left [ \cos t \begin{pmatrix}
0\\ 1

\end{pmatrix}-\sin t\begin{pmatrix}
-1\\ 0

\end{pmatrix} \right ]+c_2\left [ \cos t \begin{pmatrix}
0\\ 1

\end{pmatrix}+\sin t\begin{pmatrix}
1\\ 0

\end{pmatrix} \right ]$, But I could not get the answer which is $X(t)=sin(t)$ and $y(t)=\cos (t)$.

Comment: I think you made a mistake becaise both solutions are the same.. cjeck again your work @Mathxx

Comment: I got $X(t)=c_1e^{it}\begin{pmatrix}
-i\\1 

\end{pmatrix}+c_2e^{-it}\begin{pmatrix}i
\\ 1

\end{pmatrix}$

But I'm not sure did I transform it into trigonometry correctly.

Comment: I think that your answer is correct ...You just need to add vectors to get the solution you posted @Mathxx

Comment: Yes. I did. But I do not know how to get rid of the $i$.

Comment: Sum the vectors you will find the solution of the book @Mathxx

Comment: https://ibb.co/0sGG7bh

This is what I got. I do not know how to proceed. Can you help me out?

Comment: I think you made a sign mistake somewhere but your solution is close to the correct one @Mathxx

Comment: I posted the correct solution od the system...@Mathxx

Comment: how you actually got rid of the ‘i’?

Comment: It's a constant @Mathxx It dosent matter that the constants $c_1,c_2$ are complex.

Comment: I’m not sure where is my mistake. I can’t find your answer .

Comment: @Mathxx  note that $e^{it}=\cos t + i \sin  t$  and $e^ {-it}=\cos t -i \sin t$ Pay attention to the sign of the sine function

Comment: Yes. But still i can’t get the answer. https://ibb.co/6Z8W7J3

Comment: I added a hull answer I jope its more clear now @Mathxx Jabe a nice evening

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}
\pars{\dot{\mrm{x}}\pars{t} \atop \dot{\mrm{y}}\pars{t}} & =
\overbrace{\pars{%
\begin{array}{rr}
\ds{0} & \ds{1}
\\
\ds{-1} & \ds{0}
\end{array}}}^{\ds{\ic\sigma_{y}}}
\pars{\mrm{x}\pars{t} \atop \mrm{y}\pars{t}}
\label{1}\tag{1}
\end{align}
$\ds{\sigma_{y}}$ is a [Pauli Matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pauli_matrices) which satisfies
$\ds{\sigma_{y}^{2} = {\bf 1} =\ Identity\ Matrix}$. The (\ref{1}) formal solution is given by
\begin{align}
\pars{\mrm{x}\pars{t} \atop \mrm{y}\pars{t}} & =
\expo{\large\ic\sigma_{y}t}\pars{\mrm{x}\pars{0} \atop \mrm{y}\pars{0}}
\label{2}\tag{2}
\end{align}
Note that
$\ds{\pars{\totald[2]{}{t} + 1}\expo{\large\ic\sigma_{y}t} = 0}$ with $\ds{\left. \expo{\large\ic\sigma_{y}t}
\right\vert_{\ t\ =\ 0} = {\bf 1}}$ and
$\ds{\left. \totald{\expo{\large\ic\sigma_{y}t}}{t}
\right\vert_{\ t\ =\ 0} = \ic\sigma_{y}}$. Then,
$$
\expo{\large\ic\sigma_{y}t} = \cos\pars{t}{\bf 1} + \sin\pars{t}\ic\sigma_{y} =
\pars{%
\begin{array}{rr}
\ds{\cos\pars{t}} & \ds{\sin\pars{t}}
\\
\ds{-\sin\pars{t}} & \ds{\cos\pars{t}}
\end{array}}
$$
With this result, (\ref{2}) becomes
\begin{align}
& \mbox{} \\
& \bbx{\left\{\begin{array}{rcrcr}
\ds{\mrm{x}\pars{t}} & \ds{=} &
\ds{\mrm{x}\pars{0}\cos\pars{t}} & \ds{+} & \ds{\mrm{y}\pars{0}\sin\pars{t}}
\\[1mm]
\ds{\mrm{y}\pars{t}} & \ds{=} &
\ds{-\mrm{x}\pars{0}\sin\pars{t}} & \ds{+} & \ds{\mrm{y}\pars{0}\cos\pars{t}}
\end{array}\right.} \\ &
\end{align}